# How to get the maximum directory depth of the current working directory

Tags: windows, recursion, batch-file, directory, cmd

I'm trying myself at [Windows batch programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) at the moment. So far so good, and I could nicely figure out how to delete empty directories and files that were older than x days. The problem is that, if I start the deleting of the empty directories, and we assume that the process only runs once, there always will be new empty folders left on the condition that the current working directory has such a structure:

```
Empty Folder

     Empty Folder

          Empty Folder

               Empty Folder

Folder

Folder

...
```

In this case, only the last empty folder will be deleted, but then there is again an empty folder. For this I need to calculate the maximum directory depth (in that case 3 --> because of the three sub-directory structure). If I would have had this depth I could run the deleting process x (dir-depth) times. How I can get the directory depth in Windows batch programming?

Comment: Yes i already remove it recursively but thats the normal Routine and this does not solve my Problem. If you think about the Problem more deeply, you'll notice that this is not a Problem of the recursive process, as far as i understand it.

Comment: sorting the list in reverse order handles this issue - Endoro has the solution in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad /s "root folder" ^| sort /r') do rd "%%~a"
```

Comment: What does the ^| mean ? Do i have to replace the "root folder" to the folder on which the script is running? And why do you use /f and not /d ... i thought /f is for files and not for directories.

Comment: I cannot compute this command. Somehow the cmd tells me that the | cannot be used syntactically at that Position. What is wrong?

Comment: @LordTribual the command works. Replace `"root folder"` with the path to the start folder, eg. `"D:\Empty Folder"`  and do not remove `^|`. For help enter `help for` at the command line.

Comment: So cool! Now it works. Thank you very much, but can you explain me the last part `('dir /b /ad /s "root folder" ^| sort /r') do rd "%%~a"` of your Statement ? What is the difference between yours and mine `for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /AD /B /S %directory% /R') do (rd "%%i" 2>nul && echo DELETE %%i)`

Comment: the `dir /ad /s` command searches the `start folder` for directories and makes an unsorted list. `sort /r` sorts the list reverse, longest names on top. Now `rd` can delete these longest (= deepest) folder path names first.